# HTML5 Audio Tag Plays, but Controls Not Working as Expected

Tags: html, audio, twilio, html5-audio

So, the audio tag works and plays audio fine, but the seek/navigation doesn't work. It doesn't travel with the audio and you can't seek/navigate through the player. This is what it looks like for a 1-minute and 23-second audio clip:

[image]

Also, when the player is done, the time/duration is *off*. I don't know how else to explain it. This is what it looks like after:

[image]

This is the code for the player:

```
<audio controls preload="auto">
    <source src="https://third.party.com/file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

I've never really worked with the `<audio>` tag before, so maybe there are nuances I'm missing, but it seemed pretty straight-forward. Am I missing something?

---

**Edit** - More Details

I've added a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/py3je9qx/). Also, this appears to happen with longer audio clips, so this may be bandwidth related. When a clip is a few seconds (< 10s) it seems to work fine most of the time.

Comment: What is the browser used to get that strange behavior ? Did you try other browser (just to see if it is browser related) ? Did you try with different mp3 sources (just to be sure that the cause is not a corrupted mp3) ?

Comment: could you add it into a fiddle so that we could see it for ourselves?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - I've tried different browsers, same thing. Updated initial post with JSFiddle link and URL used (it's a Twilio API recording).

Comment: @RachelGallen - Done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this too.  This is a Twilio mp3.  It seems to be a problem with Twilio's mp3 file formats or the response headers.  The mp3 is being recognized as a stream.  This may also be intentional.

A simple fix - Just switch to the `wav` version of the file.  Use ".wav" as an extension (or leave it off and it defaults to wav).

```
<audio controls preload="auto">
  <source src="https://api.twilio.com/<account>/Recordings/<recording>.wav">
</audio>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzw8Lutb/)

Comment: This was definitely a Twilio problem. Interesting that it works as `wav` format.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this without knowing what was going on and spent hours looking for answers. My MP3 files are more than 30 min in length and on Firefox the MP3 controls worked pretty well, but in Chrome I couldn't make the seek/forward control to work.

After trying this page's JSFiddles and debugging, I found out that the HTML5 code wasn't the problem. So I followed an approach serving the MP3 through my ruby on rails backend 'send_file' function and it finally worked on Chrome. I added a "/stream" route, and in its controller I returned the send_file function. Just like this:

```
send_file path_to_MP3_file,
  filename: File.basename(path_to_MP3_file),
  type: Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension("mp3"),
  disposition: 'inline',
  stream: true,
  buffer_size: 4096
```

I had to register the MP3 MIME type on an initializer file for the "lookup_by_extension" method to work, so I used:

```
Mime::Type.register "audio/mpeg", :mp3
```

Now, I'm stuck trying to make the controls work in iOS, but that's another story. I'll post an update if I get it working for the mobile version :)

**UPDATE**:

Not having the timeline control on iOS browsers was specifically related to the component's width. Forcing it to a min-width did the work, but messed up the design in narrow devices (like iPhone 5).

I ended up changing my CSS, forcing some [webkit-pseudo-elements](https://gist.github.com/afabbro/3759334) and styling to something like this:

```
  audio {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 280px;
  }

  audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
    display: inline;
  }

  audio::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display {
    display: flex;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you change the `preload` to `'none'` instead of `'auto'` it works fine

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/py3je9qx/1/) or run snippet

```html
<audio controls preload="none">
  <source src="https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACaa255ecd514b787c2f0358486f07a106/Recordings/REf5c1e1f1e048894182132ba0ce763183.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: it still doesn't explain the odd behaviour on the 'auto', i grant you, but it works!

Comment: It seems to only work for audio clips shorter than about 5 minutes. Anything above that has the same issues. This certainly gives me good direction on where to look on how to fix it.

Comment: @Andrew i just tried it with a sound file over 10 mins long and it works perfectly https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/qxhrtwza/  your problem is most likely caused by a bug in the twilio api rather than anything to do with the audio file or tag

Comment: Yeah, it might be twilio. I'm calling this several times in the same page. I'm going to spend some more time in this and see what I can find.

Comment: still can't seek

Answer (score 0):

I just fount this hint [here](http://dotnet.tech.ubc.ca/CourseWiki/index.php?title=IP491F13A) :

> Note preload supercedes autobuffer in the latest HTML5 spec. Previously autobuffer took a boolean value specifying whether the file is to be buffered in advance. Currently, browsers are making the transition from autobuffer to preload so we suggest that you use both attributes for the time being.

So you should use this in order to force preload.

```
<audio controls preload="auto" autobuffer>
```

See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/py3je9qx/4/)

Comment: Good idea, but it doesn't seem to work either. I'm thinking it might be because I'm loading several audio clips in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when playing MP3 files through the HTML5 `<audio>` player. Some files worked on Mozilla in WIN7, but not on some Android devices.

Namely, in the Audacity program, if you export your **mono** recording as an MP3 **stereo** recording, it remains visible in the program as a **mono** recording, but the **file size remains the same** as for the **stereo** recording.

Well, such MP3 files made mistakes during my playback (on Android devices).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<audio controls preload="none">
  <source src="https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACaa255ecd514b787c2f0358486f07a106/Recordings/REf5c1e1f1e048894182132ba0ce763183.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

```html
<audio controls preload="none">
  <source src="https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACaa255ecd514b787c2f0358486f07a106/Recordings/REf5c1e1f1e048894182132ba0ce763183.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It is working for chrome and edge beta also! Great